# gitlab runner doesn't know about tags

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I use tags for auto-versioning, but I ran into a problem.
Gitlab CI/CD Runner does not output tags when running `git describe --always --long --tags --dirty`

I tried doing `git fetch --all --tags`, but that didn't help. Still no tags.
How does gilab runner copy the code to build? Maybe there's something I don't know.

Comment: Can you show exact message when you describe or fetch tags?

Comment: @MuravyevMaxim, `git describe --always --long --tags --dirty --match "major_*"`

Answer (score 1):

Default [Git strategy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-strategy) is `fetch` and [default depth](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone) for `git fetch` command is 20 since GitLab version 14.7. That means that by default only tags from last 20 commits will be fetched.

One of the possible ways to change this behavior is to add `--tags` flag to default `git fetch` command via `GIT_FETCH_EXTRA_FLAGS` [variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-fetch-extra-flags):

```
variables:
  GIT_FETCH_EXTRA_FLAGS: --prune --quiet --tags
```

The block could be added globally or per-job. `--prune --quiet` - are default flags.

With this configuration all tags will be fetched from remote.